# Can't French citizens in the United States apply to a Chinese L (tourist) visa through an agency?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas, french-citizens, us-permanent-residents

Applications for a Chinese L (tourist) visas in the United States can't  be mailed directly to the Chinese Embassy/Consulate. As a result, many people use third-party agencies who accept applications by mail and drop them to the proper Chinese Embassy/Consulate.

I read on the website of one such agency, http://www.mychinavisa.com/special-requirements ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181110024005/http://www.mychinavisa.com/special-requirements)):

> Citizens of certain countries, such as France, Turkey, Nigeria, etc., are required to apply in person at the Chinese Embassy/Consulates. The list can change without notice.

I didn't see this restriction on the other agencies' websites I have looked at.

Can't French citizens in the United States apply to a Chinese L (tourist) visa through an agency?

I'm interested in the case where the French citizens are also permanent resident of the United States (= have a green card).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked a few more people and it seems that indeed French citizens in the United States who want to apply to a Chinese L (tourist) visa have to apply at the Chinese consulate/embassy in person.

- French citizens typically (always?) require in person interview. It is
  not written rule. The reason I was given is that the French government requires Chinese citizens in the United States to apply for French visa in person, so the Chinese are reciprocating (which I understand 100%). https://www.visahq.com/france/requirements/china/resident-united-states/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181113195949/https://www.visahq.com/france/requirements/china/resident-united-states/)): "The applicant must reserve an appointment and appear in person at the nearest Consulate of France to have their fingerprints registered."
- Agencies can, however, provide pickup service after one submits the application.