# Is there any minimum stay required in the next/onward country when applying for a visa-free transit entry in China?

Tags: transit, china, visa-free-entry

I plan to enter Mainland China with the [transit-without-visa (TWOV) program](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Visa_policy_of_China&oldid=879079865#72-hour_stay_/_144-hour_stay).

I fly from country X to China, then fly from China to country Y. Is there any minimum stay required in country Y when applying for a visa-free transit entry in China?

E.g., if I fly country X -> China for 144 hours -> country Y for 2 hours ->  country X, is that still fine to get the visa-free entry in China? I'm asking as I wonder whether the Chinese immigration officials would think that in that case country Y is the transit place and the state in China  is the purpose of the trip, and if so, whether that would represent a reason to deny entry to China.

Comment: You are not required to show the flight ticket from Country Y -> Country X to Chinese immigration, as its not their business on where you are going after that.

However, as you say, your main destination is china. :)

Comment: Is the only purpose of your flight to country Y to be eligible for the TWOV program in China? If so, is that for cost reasons? If so, it's probably cheaper to get a proper Chinese visa and skip the detour through country Y, booking a regular round trip.

Comment: @GregHewgill two purposes: faster to get, and as a French citizen currently living in the United States, I [have to go physically to a Chinese embassy to apply for a visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125462/1810), which is time consuming.

Comment: That makes sense, particularly if you don't have a local Chinese consulate.

Comment: A potential pitfall here would be that you could get rebooked on an itinerary that is X -> China -> X by the airline if all is on one ticket and Y is not explicitly booked as an intermediate destination (which in your case I doubt it is, you just happen to be routed throuch X). In that case TWOV would no longer apply.